# Copy every 8 values from a df column, to one row in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe and want to copy a group of 8 values to a new dataframe, but every value of the group has to be in a new column. Then the next 8 values should be copied to the new dataframe.

my code so far is not getting passt the first row of the new dataframe:

```
kk = 1
jj = 0
while(kk <= 8):
    df_new["Col" + str(kk)] = df_old.loc[jj, "ColumnName"]
    kk += 1
    jj += 1
```

Output:

```
Df_old                Df_new    
Index ColumnName      Index Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8
    0      val1          0  val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8
    1      val2
    2      val3
    3      val4
    4      val5
    5      val6
    6      val7
    7      val8
   ...      ...
    n      valn
```

what I expect:

```
    Df_old                Df_new    
    Index ColumnName      Index Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8
        0      val1          0  val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8
        1      val2          1  val2 val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8 val9
        2      val3          2  val3 val4 val5 val6 val7 val8 val9 val10
        3      val4
        4      val5
        5      val6
        6      val7
        7      val8
```

I'm really stuck here.

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Use simple `.T` , say, `DF_old.T`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to rename your columns:

```
df = df.T.add_prefix('Col').reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print(df)

   Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7
0  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  val7  val8
```

---

**Or** if you want to start with `1` at your first column perse:

```
df = df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = ['Col'+str(x+1) for x in df.columns]
```

---

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  Col8
0  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6  val7  val8
```

Comment: Thank you, but I work with two different df. I want to copy the first 8 values of Df_old to row 0 in the new df.

Comment: In your question you say _`to a new dataframe`_ . This is a whole different question, can't re edit my entire answer. You can ask a new question or edit your question and hope someone answers here. @Peet

Comment: Edited my question. Hopefully you'll now understand my question.